# fetching the precise date time including milliseconds the time photo is taken from image file in php

Tags: php, exif

I am developing a Web Application using PHP Laravel that involves some processing as well. What I am doing now is I am trying to extract the time taken from the image file when user uploads the file. I can extract the data using exif_read_data function like this.

```
$exif_data = exif_read_data($file);
echo $exif_data['DateTimeOriginal'];
```

When I retrieve, the format is YYYY:MM:DD H:m:s. But I also need to know the milli/nano seconds as well after seconds. So, is there a way to retrieve more precise time the photo is taken from the image file and how can I do it?

Comment: `microtime();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php for the current time, unless the image has been saved with more exact time data then no

Comment: No, I would like to retrieve the time photo is taken from the exif/meta data of the photo.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a field in the exif data that goes beyond `second`. https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the link. The document you linked to indeed mentions `SubSecTime` `SubSecTimeOriginal` `SubSecTimeDigitized`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should be able to get the millisecond/nanosecond resolution from the sub-second tags: `SubsecTime`, `SubsecTimeOriginal` or `SubsecTimeDigitized`, which are the array keys of the EXIF information.

Comment: Thanks so much, that helped. Nice meeting u as well.

Comment: And that's part of the standard. https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/21773296 mentions http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF from year 2002 which at page 24 specifies `SubSecTime` `SubSecTimeOriginal` `SubSecTimeDigitized`.